# Error while updating. near "U": syntax error

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

When i try to update an entry in my table, i got this stack error:

```
Error while updating. near "U": syntax error
```

My relevant code is this:

```
const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt    *updateStmt;


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            const char*sql="Update quiz set etat=1 where id=?";

            sqlite3_prepare(contactDB, sql, 1, &updateStmt, NULL);

            sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 0, id_quiz);
            sqlite3_step(updateStmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
                NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));


            sqlite3_close(contactDB);
        }
```

Note: `id_quiz` contain an int value like 1, 2, etc.

Comment: can you try `sqlite3_prepare_v2` instead of `sqlite3_prepare`.  The [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) discourages use of the latter and notes that you may receive more finally-grained error codes.

Comment: Same issue even with the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` :(

Answer (score 0):

In the bind int i would use the 1 index instead of 0

Comment: Same issue i still got, the stack above indicates that i have syntax error in the query although it looks fine.